# what is the informix connection string to run a sql file through windows command prompt?

Tags: database, database-connection, informix, database-connectivity

I am new to informix, I would like to know what is the connection string of informix to run a sql file through windows command prompt. for example to run sql file in windows command prompt with mssql we use command " sqlcmd -S myServer\instanceName -i C:\myScript.sql  "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Informix has no such tool for client side. On Windows machine you can install ClientSDK or JDBC driver. ClientSDK comes with ODBC driver. Having ODBC and JDBC drivers you can use many open source SQL editors or even create simple utility which will be able to run SQL commands from file. For such simple tasks I prefer Jython+Informix JDBC driver.

On server side you can use [db-access](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0406chong/index.html). I believe Web interface (ISA Informix Server Administrator) uses it via CGI or similar technology.

You should also read great Jonathan answer to: [Remote Informix 11.5 Command Line Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803392/remote-informix-11-5-command-line-client)